# Can I insert rows next to a locked column in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, cells

If I lock cells `A1:A3000`, is there a way to insert rows in columns `B-Z`?

I highlight them and I don't get the option to insert even though it is selected in the lock options. (Bottom line is that I need column A static, not to move.)

Any ideas? Is it even possible?

Better yet, is there any way to have formulas in column A static, as I insert rows in column B? Column A formulas change cell location when I do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [INDIRECT function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/indirect-HP005209139.aspx) to always refer to the same cell regardless of inserting rows etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s my mock-up of your situation:

[image]

Select all the cells below where you want to insert the row(s). You can do this with the mouse, or by typing `B5:Z7` into the Name Box (the thing at the far left of the Formula Bar).

[image]

Then click on the border of the selected rectangle and drag it down as many rows as you want.

[image]

[image]